# How To delete topic which is run in multinode multi cluster HA kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have set up kafka version 2.11-0.10.1.0 in multinode multicluster environment .In kafka server.properties I already added **delete.enable.topic=true** in all the 3 machines.

I am using command for delete topic is ,
**./bin/kafka-topic.sh --zookeeper ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 --delete --topic topicname**

but It's not deleting ,showing **topic name -mark for deletion**

So everytime I am clearing kafka-logs and zookeeper logs for delete topic .

Anybody having any idea to delete using command prompt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general everything you are doing sounds right, I suspect that your problem is a simple typo.

The parameter to enable topic deletion in Kafka is called: *delete.topic.enable* not, as you stated above: *delete.enable.topic*.

This would cause deletion to revert to its default value, which is *false* and result in the behavior you are seeing.

Correcting this and restarting should fix your issue and delete all topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot  .This is a serious mistake I have done ..You saved a lot of time for me .